# Prevent Generation of Log File with Python logging

Tags: python, logging

I have a simple script that I run as an exe file on Windows. However, when I am developing the script, I run it from the command line and use the `logging` module to output debug info to a log file. I would like to turn off the generation of the log file for my production code. How would I go about doing that?

This is the logging config I have setup now:

```
import logging

... 

 logging.basicConfig(filename='file.log',
        filemode="w",
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="%(asctime)s: %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
        datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',
        )
...

logging.debug("Debug message")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the generation of an empty log file for production, you can simply increase the threshold of logging to a level above `logging.DEBUG`, such as `logging.INFO`, so that messages logged with `logging.debug` won't get output to the log file:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='file.log', # creates an empty file.log
        filemode="w",
        level=logging.INFO,
        format="%(asctime)s: %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
        datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',
        )

logging.debug("Debug message") # nothing would happen
logging.info("FYI") # logs 'FYI'
```

If you don't want logging to function at all, an easy approach is to override `logging` with a `Mock` object:

```
import logging
from unittest.mock import Mock

environment = 'production'

if environment == 'production':
    logging = Mock()

...

logging.basicConfig(...) # nothing would happen

logging.debug(...) # nothing would happen
```